# How to map a key to scroll back in zathura

Tags: zathura

I'd like to map `b` to scroll back one screen in Zathura.
I tried:

```
map <B> <C-b>
```

But it returns the error:

```
warning: Invalid special key value or mode: B
```

Based on this [bug report](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/issues/36), I managed to achieve the functionality with

```
map b feedkeys <C-b>
```

But zathura returns the following error on every  `b` key pressed:

```
(zathura:6582): Gdk-WARNING **: 15:26:58.771: 
Event with type 8 not holding a GdkDevice. 
It is most likely synthesized outside Gdk/GTK+
```

Answer (score 1):

In man `zathurarc`, you can find `scroll` under "Shortcut functions".
You can also set the total displacement of the scroll with `scroll-step`.

To make the map work, add this to `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc`:

```
set scroll-step 300
map B scroll up
map b scroll down
```

Fine tune `scroll-step` to the value you like best. And if you ask me how
on earth I discovered the necessary `up` and `down` arguments, believe me
that it was on blind trials and errors. Although Zathura is great, it is
bad documented when it comes to more detailed customizations.

Comment: This answer, while a bit salty, saved me at least 30 minutes today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From `man zathurarc`

use `map b scroll full-up`
Each key can be bound to a shortcut function as
`map [mode] <binding> <shortcut function> <argument>`
where the mode is optional.
In my example, the mode is not given, the binding is the single letter b , the shortcut function is scroll with an optional argument of full up.
Each shortcut functions can optional arguments, a list of possible arguments are listed in the documentation. But what arguments each function can take is not documented.
Through educated guessing, I found that the scroll function can take the argument full-up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).